# Referencing data.table columns in Functions in R

Tags: r, function, data.table

In SAP, I upload text files of transactions that are identified with two known fields: "Document No" and "Position". Multiple transactions in the file can have one UniqueID. Transactions that share the same UniqueID have one Document No, and have serial Positions. Below is a sample of the text file.

| UniqueID | Document No | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 1 | 1 |
| 200 | 1 | 2 |
| 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 300 | 2 | 2 |
| 400 | 3 | 1 |
| 400 | 3 | 2 |

I managed to write a code to produce this Document No and Position serial for a sample data (tblSAP). The code below works well. However, I need to have this code as a function as I have many processed tables that need to be converted into SAP text files. Hence, I need to convert this code into a function.

```
library(data.table)
# sample data table
tblSAP <- data.table(
  UniqueID = c(200,200,300,300,400,400)
  
)

# code to generate Document No and Position fields

## Sort entire tblSAP table
tblSAP <- setorder(tblSAP,cols=UniqueID)

## create a temp table of UniqueID 
dfUniqueID <- tblSAP[,.(UniqueID)]

## create "Document No" and "Position" count
DT1 <- dfUniqueID[,.N, by=.(UniqueID, "Document No"=rleid(UniqueID))]

## extend UniqueIDs with Positions
DT2 <- dfUniqueID[,seq_len(.N), by = UniqueID] |> 
  setnames(old = "V1",new = "Position")

## Join UniqueID, Document Number, and Positions in one table
DT3 <- DT1[DT2,on = .(UniqueID)][,-c("N")]

## Bind SAP Upload table with the columns of Document No and Position from DT3 table
tblSAP <- cbind(tblSAP,DT3[,-c("UniqueID")])
```

When I converted the code into a function, I only replaced the UniqueID by an input parameter in the function as shown. But it seems there's something wrong in referencing the tblSAP column (UniqueID) in the function. I receive the error of "Error in setorderv(x, cols, order, na.last) :
some columns are not in the data.table: IdFld".

Here's the function that I wrote:

```
# function to generate Document No and Position fields
SAPDocPos <- function(tblSAP,IdFld){
  
  ## Sort entire tblSAP table
  tblSAP <- setorder(tblSAP,cols=IdFld)
  
  ## create a temp table of IdFld 
  dfUniqueID <- tblSAP[,.(IdFld)]
  
  ## create "Document No" and "Position" count
  DT1 <- dfUniqueID[,.N, by=.(IdFld, "Document No"=rleid(IdFld))]
  
  ## extend IdFlds with Positions
  DT2 <- dfUniqueID[,seq_len(.N), by = IdFld] %>% 
    setnames(old = "V1",new = "Position")
  
  ## Join IdFlds, Document Number, and Positions in one table
  DT3 <- DT1[DT2,on = .(IdFld)][,-c("N")]
  
  ## Bind SAP Upload table with the columns of Document No and Position from DT3 table
  tblSAP <- cbind(tblSAP,DT3[,-c("UniqueID")])
  return(tblSAP)
}

SAPDocPos(tblSAP,UniqueID)
```

Assistance in resolving this case is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes:

- in order to use the *symbol* `UniqueID`, we need to use `deparse(substitute(.))` to convert it into a character; in general I tend to recommend against using non-standard evaluation (as you are attempting to do here), especially when the only value it adds is the omission of quotes ... however, I'll keep it here for demonstration
- `setorder` requires non-standard evaluation, but we can use `setorderv` which expects a character vector
- I'll use `.SDcols=` to subset by columns instead of attempting `.(UniqueID)`
- for `DT1`, the `by=` can also be a character vector, but that requires that `` `Document No` `` be pre-defined, so this is updated a little
- perhaps just a nuance, I shifted from `%>%` to `|>` to reduce dependencies; not required if you already depend on `dplyr` or `magrittr` elsewhere
- just a preference, but the literal `return(.)` statement is only *needed* when you need the function to return a value earlier in the code, such as in an `if` block; since a function always returns the value of the last expression, we can omit it. (Calling `return(tblSAP)` explicitly is fine but adds unnecessary function calls to the stack.)

```r
SAPDocPos <- function(tblSAP,IdFld){
  IdFld <- deparse(substitute(IdFld))
  
  ## Sort entire tblSAP table
  tblSAP <- setorderv(tblSAP,cols=IdFld)
  
  ## create a temp table of IdFld 
  dfUniqueID <- tblSAP[,.SD, .SDcols = IdFld]
  
  ## create "Document No" and "Position" count
  DT1 <- dfUniqueID[, `Document No` := rleid(get(IdFld))][, .N, by = c(IdFld, "Document No")]
  
  ## extend IdFlds with Positions
  DT2 <- dfUniqueID[, seq_len(.N), by = IdFld] |>
    setnames(old = "V1", new = "Position")
  
  ## Join IdFlds, Document Number, and Positions in one table
  DT3 <- DT1[DT2, on = c(IdFld)][,-c("N")]
  
  ## Bind SAP Upload table with the columns of Document No and Position from DT3 table
  tblSAP <- cbind(tblSAP, DT3[, -c(IdFld), with=FALSE])

  tblSAP
}

SAPDocPos(tblSAP, UniqueID)
#    UniqueID Document No Position
#       <num>       <int>    <int>
# 1:      200           1        1
# 2:      200           1        2
# 3:      300           2        1
# 4:      300           2        2
# 5:      400           3        1
# 6:      400           3        2
```

If you want to go "all in" on `data.table`'s referential (in-place) semantics, you can add some `set` calls (more-direct `data.table` value-setting) to add the columns to the original frame. NOTE: this is in-line with `data.table` but at odds with base-R's copy-on-write semantics.

```r
SAPDocPos <- function(tblSAP,IdFld){
  IdFld <- deparse(substitute(IdFld))
  
  ## Sort entire tblSAP table
  tblSAP <- setorderv(tblSAP,cols=IdFld)
  
  ## create a temp table of IdFld 
  dfUniqueID <- tblSAP[,.SD, .SDcols = IdFld]
  
  ## create "Document No" and "Position" count
  DT1 <- dfUniqueID[, `Document No` := rleid(get(IdFld))][, .N, by = c(IdFld, "Document No")]
  
  ## extend IdFlds with Positions
  DT2 <- dfUniqueID[, seq_len(.N), by = IdFld] |>
    setnames(old = "V1", new = "Position")
  
  ## Join IdFlds, Document Number, and Positions in one table
  DT3 <- DT1[DT2, on = c(IdFld)][,-c("N")]
  
  set(tblSAP, i = NULL, j = "Document No", value = DT3[["Document No"]])
  set(tblSAP, i = NULL, j = "Position", value = DT3[["Position"]])

  tblSAP
}

tblSAP
#    UniqueID
#       <num>
# 1:      200
# 2:      200
# 3:      300
# 4:      300
# 5:      400
# 6:      400
SAPDocPos(tblSAP, UniqueID) # not re-assigning over tblSAP
tblSAP
#    UniqueID Document No Position
#       <num>       <int>    <int>
# 1:      200           1        1
# 2:      200           1        2
# 3:      300           2        1
# 4:      300           2        2
# 5:      400           3        1
# 6:      400           3        2
```

Comment: Thank you indeed, @r2evans. That was very helpful. I still have a couple points to clarify in your code please:

1. When I replace the **UniqueID** by the parameter input **IdFld** in the last line that binds the tables, I receive the error of (Error in -c(IdFld) : invalid argument to unary operator). 

2. I can't figure out how to reflect the function's output to the original table in the Global Env. The objective of the function is to modify a table but it seems that with this code it only produces a table in the consol without affecting the original table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I see. Check out the edit (using `with=FALSE`). Hope that helps!

Comment: Super! Thank you. But for my second part of the question (see my previous comment) regarding modifying the original table in the Global Env. How can I do it?

Comment: Isn't that what my second function does? Or, as with everything else in R, just assign back onto the variable, as in `tblSAP <- SAPDocPos(tblSAP, UniqueID)`.